# How do I filter by 'keywords' with angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, search, filter

I'm trying to create a robust filtering system with basic HTML & angular.js, so far with the help of a few kind people on here, I've ended up with this:

http://codepen.io/liamtarpey/pen/jfvDK

It works fine, the only issue is if you type something backwards, for example if the user searches for: 'taco mexican' or even 'mexican taco', you'd get no results at all.

Is there a way to use the filter as more of a keyword filter rather than a string filter?

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for someone else's filter code but to answer the overall general question, yes you can create custom filters. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Comment: This is not really an Angular question, it is a search question. You should reword and re-tag it.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the tags and reworded.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate through every property for every word in the search term. This works:

```
$scope.search = function(user) {
  var match = true;
  $scope.query.split(" ").forEach(function(word) {
    if (match === true) {
      var wordMatch = false;
      for (var prop in user) {
        if (user.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          if(user[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) > -1) wordMatch = true;
        }
      }
    }
    match = wordMatch;
  });
  return match
}
```